# trying to make call from IOS

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use url_launcher so that through a button it takes me to the dialer of my phone to make a call. In android it works perfectly but when I run it in IOS it does not work, it does nothing, I don't know if something is missing in the code, I appreciate your help

This is the code I am using:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
       
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

 
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final String _phoneNumber = '318654378';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Call Number'),
            onPressed: () {
              if (Platform.isAndroid) {
                // _callNumber();
                launch('tel://$_phoneNumber');
              } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
                launch('tel://$_phoneNumber');
              }
            }),
      ),

    );
  }

}
```

Any idea what is going on

Comment: Are you testing it on a physical device or an iOS emulator?

Comment: I am testing it on an emulator

Comment: iOS Phone application is not available on emulator. You have to use a physical device